# How to check if a phone has NFC in its hard ware

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an application that makes use of NFC tags,

Is there a way to detect if the device it is running on has NFC ? and if it does not then i can display an alternative like possibly manually entering in the data rather than swiping the  phone over the NFC tag?

If the phone has got the nfc feature then i would obviously ask them to turn it on if its currently disabled and then prompt them to swipe the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) :

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC)`